# How do I automatically change the value of a text variable depending on whether I export to epub vs pdf?

Tags: adobe-indesign, epub

I'm working on a book layout in InDesign. The book will be published both to paperback and to e-book readers.

The two formats (paperback and e-book) will have different ISBNs from each other. Thus, I want to define an `ISBN` text variable in InDesign; then, when I export it, the text variable will change based on whether I'm exporting an `.epub` file or a `.pdf` file.

Is there a way to do this in InDesign? The only way I can figure out how to do it at the moment is to include *both* ISBNs in the text, using character styles to render the e-book ISBN as transparent (thus making it invisible), then using CSS to render it visible and hide the paperback ISBN when exporting it as an `.epub` file.

But I have to think there's a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: It can be a script that changes contents of the variable(s) or switch between two predefined variables any time you run it. This way all you need is to run the script before you export your document — a semi-automatic solution. It could a full-automatic solution as well — a script that exports your book into two formats and changes the isbn along the way. But it's possible only if you have a very stable workflow and you don't need to change properties for every single book.

Comment: Have you considered using InDesign's "Conditional Text" feature?

Comment: @user1754036 Thanks — that's close to what I'm looking for. I'd just want something that automatically switches conditions based on whether I'm exporting to PDF vs. ePub! I'm surprised there isn't a "Conditions" section of the export dialogs for PDF/ePub where one can do this.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to add features to the standard export dialogs. Perhaps you could use the Conditional Text feature, then use an event listener to listen for attempts to export files, then trap the attempt, present a dialog asking if the user intends to export to PDF or ePub, then show/hide Conditional Text appropriately before moving forward with the standard export. The user would then need to be consistent in that dialog. To make it safer, one must rewrite the entire export dialog and present that instead of moving forward with the normal export.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of the simplest solution. Suppose you have 3 variables:

- `isbn` (used in the layout)
- `paper isbn`
- `ebook isbn`

[image]

this script shows the dialog window to assign the contents of `paper isbn` or `epub isbn` to the variable `isbn` (a current isbn used in the layout):

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;
var paper_isbn = doc.textVariables.itemByName('isbn paper');
var ebook_isbn = doc.textVariables.itemByName('isbn ebook');
var isbn = doc.textVariables.itemByName('isbn');
var current_isbn = isbn.variableOptions.contents;

var win = new Window('dialog','Select ISBN');

var paper_checkbox = win.add('radiobutton');
paper_checkbox.text = 'Paper: ' + paper_isbn.variableOptions.contents;
paper_checkbox.value = paper_isbn.variableOptions.contents == current_isbn;
paper_checkbox.onClick = function() { current_isbn = paper_isbn.variableOptions.contents }

var ebook_checkbox = win.add('radiobutton');
ebook_checkbox.text = 'eBook: ' + ebook_isbn.variableOptions.contents;
ebook_checkbox.value = ebook_isbn.variableOptions.contents == current_isbn;
ebook_checkbox.onClick = function() { current_isbn = ebook_isbn.variableOptions.contents }

var buttons = win.add("group");
buttons.orientation = "row";
var ok = buttons.add("button",undefined,"OK");
var cancel = buttons.add("button",undefined,"Cancel");

win.defaultElement = ok;
win.cancelElement  = cancel;

if (win.show()) isbn.variableOptions.contents = current_isbn;
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks Yuri, but what I'm really looking for is a way to automatically do this at export time. That is, if I export to EPUB vs PDF, it should automatically pick the right ISBN.

Comment: I'd propose the workflow as follows: you export in epub as usual (since there are a lot of manual features, as far as I can see) and use the epub ISBN in the layout as your main ISBN. And you add the paper book ISBN as second ISBN (as a text variable). And you make a profile for export in PDF. In this case there can be a "one-click" script that will replace the main ISBN with the the second ISBN and export the layout in PDF with the given profile and swap the ISBNs back. What do you you think?

Comment: See my another answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach. Suppose you have your layout with ebook ISBN as a main ISBN and make a epub as usual. And you have two variables:

- `isbn epub` (the main ISBN that used in the layout)
- `isbn paper`

[image]

Here is the script that changes the epub isbn with the paper isbn and export the document in PDF with the preset 'Hight Quality Print' and then changes the isbn back to the epub isbn:

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;

var isbn = doc.textVariables.itemByName('isbn epub');
var epub_isbn = isbn.variableOptions.contents;
var paper_isbn = doc.textVariables.itemByName('isbn paper').variableOptions.contents;

isbn.variableOptions.contents = paper_isbn; // change to paper isbn

var pdf_file = File(doc.filePath + '/' + doc.name.split('.').shift() + '.pdf');
var preset = app.pdfExportPresets.itemByName("[High Quality Print]");
doc.exportFile(ExportFormat.pdfType, pdf_file, false, preset);

isbn.variableOptions.contents = epub_isbn; // change back to epub isbn
```

The exported PDF looks like this (note the different ISBNs):

[image]

Perhaps you can add a couple lines to export a EPUB. Something like this:

```
var epub_file = File(doc.filePath + '/' + doc.name.split('.').shift() + '.epub');
doc.exportFile(ExportFormat.EPUB, epub_file, true);
```

But there are a lot of preferences and no presets (at least in my CS6 InDesign) so it's up to you to decide how deep it should be automated.

Here is the example how you can set a cover image in the EPUB:

```
var epub_file = File(doc.filePath + '/' + doc.name.split('.').shift() + '.epub');
doc.epubExportPreferences.coverImageFile = 'd:\\temp\\cover.jpg';
doc.epubExportPreferences.epubCover = EpubCover.EXTERNAL_IMAGE;
doc.exportFile(ExportFormat.EPUB, epub_file, false); // 'false' means no dialog window
```

The full list of properties is here:

https://www.indesignjs.de/extendscriptAPI/indesign-latest/#EPubExportPreference.html